# Strange horizontal space when using babel's \foreignlanguage in a LLNCS document

Tags: spacing, babel, lncs

The `\foreignlanguage` babel command introduces weird horizontal space at the beginning of the foreign text when used inside a document using the LLNCS (https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/llncs/llncsdoc.pdf) class. The problem doesn't appear with the default `article` class.

Minimal reproducible example:

```latex
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Ceci est \foreignlanguage{english}{a test}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of the minimal example]

How it renders with the regular `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Ceci est \foreignlanguage{english}{a test}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of the working example]

Is there something I can do to remove that space other than negative vspaces?

Comment: the class adds a `\switcht@albion` command to the language switch which contains lots of spurious spaces.

Comment: this has come up before, you could add a lot of `%` to ends of lines in llncs.cls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is buggy and adds lots of spurious space. Redo the relevant definition and report the bug:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\switcht@albion{%
\def\abstractname{Abstract.}%
\def\ackname{Acknowledgement.}%
\def\andname{and}%
\def\lastandname{\unskip, and}%
\def\appendixname{Appendix}%
\def\chaptername{Chapter}%
\def\claimname{Claim}%
\def\conjecturename{Conjecture}%
\def\contentsname{Table of Contents}%
\def\corollaryname{Corollary}%
\def\definitionname{Definition}%
\def\examplename{Example}%
\def\exercisename{Exercise}%
\def\figurename{Fig.}%
\def\keywordname{{\bf Keywords:}}%
\def\indexname{Index}%
\def\lemmaname{Lemma}%
\def\contriblistname{List of Contributors}%
\def\listfigurename{List of Figures}%
\def\listtablename{List of Tables}%
\def\mailname{{\it Correspondence to\/}:}%
\def\noteaddname{Note added in proof}%
\def\notename{Note}%
\def\partname{Part}%
\def\problemname{Problem}%
\def\proofname{Proof}%
\def\propertyname{Property}%
\def\propositionname{Proposition}%
\def\questionname{Question}%
\def\remarkname{Remark}%
\def\seename{see}%
\def\solutionname{Solution}%
\def\subclassname{{\it Subject Classifications\/}:}%
\def\tablename{Table}%
\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Ceci est \foreignlanguage{english}{a test}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Vendoring the class and adding those percent characters fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid editing a local copy you could ignore ends of lines while reading the class

```
\endlinechar=-1
\documentclass{llncs}
\endlinechar=13
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Ceci est \foreignlanguage{english}{a test}.
\end{document}
```